# Compare Today's date with a column of dates and update one cell

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to populate and update the cell in Orange - B8 (Equity). I want to check if Today's date is greater than date mentioned in Column B (Payment Date) and if it is then the value from Column H (Equity) gets copied to B8.

[image: IMAGE LINK]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter()`, like this:

`=iferror( +filter(H12:H, B12:B >= today()) )`

The `+` operator is used here to limit the result to the first match.

Comment: Thanks. It does seem to work! Although I am not understanding why `+` makes it behave this way? Any documentation I can read up on? Thank you.

Comment: I do not think there is any documentation. The `+` operator just works that way with array expressions and array formulas. You can replace it with the `array_constrain()` function if you want a documented solution.